# Radio button focus in angular material dialog

Tags: angular-material2

I'm using Angular 8 with the Angular Material components, and am running into an issue with the focus indicator in a dialog.
When there is a radio group as the first control inside a dialog, as you tab around the dialog, the first option on the group gets selected - even if there is another option selected.  i.e. when tabbing forward through the form, if the 2nd option is selected, the focus goes to the first option, then the selected option, then the buttons.

I've created a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2nkqr3 which shows the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to stop/work around it always putting focus on the first option?  (other than put something else first - unfortunately its the only thing in the dialog).

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Matt

Comment: You should always share the stackblitz link that opens the editor, not the fill screen app demo.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. Just copied out the share link.  Have fixed that up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to loop back round on this.  Turned out it was an issue in Angular material at the time: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17876

Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Its simple set `autoFocus:false` when you call dialog like

```
 openDialog()() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
      panelClass: 'modal-medium',
      data: { dialogueName: "Name" },
      autoFocus: false, //disable auto focus in dialog
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes that is a bit better, but it still looks a bit odd as you tab around the dialog, i.e. the tab goes from the last button to the first radio option, even if a different radio option is selected.  Although reverse tabbing works fine.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by tab around dialog.(Can you update your latest code above) and also in your current example its working fine

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz.  Mostly it is ok, but if I select an option (say 'Badger'), then tab through to the 'Ok' button, when I hit tab it goes to the first (unselected) radio option, then the next tab goes to the selected option.

Comment: Dear @MattHarrison Essentially a `radio button` is a `group` that functions as a single element since it retains only a single value. Tabbing to a radio group will bring you to the `first item` and then using the `arrow keys` you navigate within the group.You can cite the W3C as your source, https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/ and https://www.w3.org/wiki/RadioButton.

Comment: Hi, yes I had a look at the W3C stuff to, but then in point 4 for the radio button it says if tabbing into a radio group where an option is selected it should go to that option.

I've also added another dialog in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2nkqr3-znajkf where an input box is above the radio group (the button next to number 3).  In that case the focus goes to the selected option when tabbing into the group.

Comment: Sorry @MattHarrison I didn't get you point although you describe very well but still...

Comment: All good, I do appreciate your help.  In the new stackblitz, if you open the dialog next to button 2; when there is a selected option, after tabbing from the 'Ok' button the focus goes to the first option in the group (which may or may not be the selected option).  If you open the dialog next to button 3; when there is an option selected, after tabbing from the input text field, the focus goes to the selected option (not necessarily the first option in the group).  Does that help clarify?

Comment: Yes many thanks for detail description From all that i think you need to set `tab` index Have a look please https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_tabindex

Comment: Ok, are you suggesting setting the tab index for the radio group?  I believe the issue is the focus within the group, and that can't be changed in the html?